# Beautifulsoup, append data in columns instead of one string

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, append

I am using the following code to get some data from a website

```py
#find a list of all span elements
spans = page_body.find_all('span', {'class' : 'vehicle-tech-spec'})
 
#create a list of lines corresponding to element texts
model_details = [span.get_text() for span in spans]
print (model_details)
```

as a result I am getting this:

```
['05.2006', "137'800 km", 'Neu', '50 km', '10.2013', "97'000 km", '09.2015', "160'000 km", '04.2016', "138'000 km", '12.2017', "45'000 km", '05.2013', "90'000 km", '03.2013', "39'000 km", '01.2011', "131'400 km", '09.2017', "39'100 km", '05.2020', "9'900 km", '12.2015', "123'700 km", 'Neu', '15 km', '12.2019', "12'000 km", '06.2020', "22'200 km", 'Neu', '50 km', 'Neu', '50 km', '08.2016', "44'918 km", '03.2019', "25'725 km", '12.2017', "27'000 km"]
```

But I would like to get it like that:

| Reg.Date | Mileage |
| --- | --- |
| 05.2006 | 137'800 km |
| Neu | 50 km |
| 10.2013 | 97'000 km |
| etc. | etc. |

I am quite new to this and I am stucked with this problem now for few days. I am pretty sure for you guys it is basic!

Answer (score 0):

Just split the list into even chunks.

Here's how:

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

model_details = [
    '05.2006', "137'800 km", 'Neu', '50 km', '10.2013', "97'000 km", '09.2015',
    "160'000 km", '04.2016', "138'000 km", '12.2017', "45'000 km", '05.2013',
    "90'000 km", '03.2013', "39'000 km", '01.2011', "131'400 km", '09.2017',
    "39'100 km", '05.2020', "9'900 km", '12.2015', "123'700 km", 'Neu', '15 km',
    '12.2019', "12'000 km", '06.2020', "22'200 km", 'Neu', '50 km', 'Neu',
    '50 km', '08.2016', "44'918 km", '03.2019', "25'725 km", '12.2017', "27'000 km",
]


def chunk_it(list_to_chop: list, chunk_size: int = 2) -> list:
    return [
        list_to_chop[index:index + chunk_size] for index
        in range(0, len(list_to_chop), chunk_size)
    ]


table = tabulate(
    chunk_it(model_details),
    headers=["Column One", "Columnt Two"],
    tablefmt="pretty",
)

print(table)
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------+
| Column One | Columnt Two |
+------------+-------------+
|  05.2006   | 137'800 km  |
|    Neu     |    50 km    |
|  10.2013   |  97'000 km  |
|  09.2015   | 160'000 km  |
|  04.2016   | 138'000 km  |
|  12.2017   |  45'000 km  |
|  05.2013   |  90'000 km  |
|  03.2013   |  39'000 km  |
|  01.2011   | 131'400 km  |
|  09.2017   |  39'100 km  |
|  05.2020   |  9'900 km   |
|  12.2015   | 123'700 km  |
|    Neu     |    15 km    |
|  12.2019   |  12'000 km  |
|  06.2020   |  22'200 km  |
|    Neu     |    50 km    |
|    Neu     |    50 km    |
|  08.2016   |  44'918 km  |
|  03.2019   |  25'725 km  |
|  12.2017   |  27'000 km  |
+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You DIDNOT mention which type of data output you are looking for it.

But here's a quick example for your target.

Consider using `csv` module if you are just looking to write the data into `.csv` file instead of using `pandas`, otherwise you can use `PrettyTable` if you are looking for a table.

> pip install pandas more_itertools

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from more_itertools import chunked
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    spans = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('.vehicle-tech-spec')]
    data = list(chunked(spans, 2))
    print(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Reg.Date', 'Mileage']))


main('Url - Here')
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you help with the parent element of those spans? Maybe that way we can have a better solution. But the below fix would work for now **assuming none of the cells of table will be empty.**

```
#find a list of all span elements
spans = page_body.find_all('span', {'class' : 'vehicle-tech-spec'})
 
#create a list of lines corresponding to element texts
model_details = []
for i in range(0,len(spans),2):
   model_details.append({'reg_date': spans[i].get_text(), 'mileage': spans[i+1].get_text()})
print(model_details) #list of dictionaries with each dictionary corresponding to a line
```

Comment: Div class = "col-12 mb-4 mt-md-2 mt-sm-0 mt-xl-4" its the Div class of it. 

the reg_date and Mileage should be the new header and "model_details" can be dropped as column